# Script for Detecting Multiple Duplicates

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-answers

I was talking about this on a chat and decided to suggest it here.  I understand that this script might take a long time to run, and it doesn't necessarily have to run for every single case. But it would be very useful

**Suggestion:**
In short, the script would search Stack Exchange for duplicate questions, if the original question has a duplicate change the original to the first question

**Example:**

Question A: 
This is a question about how to send data between activities (This question already has an answer at b)

Question B: 
This question is also how to send data between activities (This question already has an answer

Question C: 
This is the original question with answers (not a duplicate)

From here the script would find questions like this and change the link to the duplicate in a from b to c.

**Why this would be useful:**

This would be incredibly useful because many duplicate questions are marked as a duplicate to another question that also is marked as a duplicate (this may go on).  Not only will this clean up the site and not have a trail of duplicate questions.

**Possible Downside**

[codeMagic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1380752/codemagic) brought up a possible downside to this

> Honestly, sometimes I find that Question (or answer) on B is more helfpul than C so I'm not sure if it's a good idea. But I understand what you're saying. It could be nice other than what I just mentioned

Comment: Path Compression algorithm detected!